# A for-do loop not working for filenames containing a space

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
for X in $(find ~/Documents/ -type f);do date -r "${X}";done
```

The above line works fine when the filenames in "/Documents/" contain no space. 
However, if the filenames contain a space, the following error will arise:

```
 No such file or directory
```

How can I make it work for filenames containing a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is one of the well known problems of using `find` and a loop.

One simple way to solve it is to dump the found list into stdout and `read` it:

```
find ~/Documents/ -type f |
while IFS= read -r filename
do
    date -r "$filename"    # ... or any other command using $filename
done
```

If your command is small enough, you can just use `-exec` key of `find`:

```
find ~/Documents/ -type f -exec date -r '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a loop, use the `-exec` argument of `find`:

```
find ~/Documents/ -type f -exec date -r {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, which is one of the reasons why you never use `for` that way to loop over the output of a command that returns file names. Also known as [Bash Pitfall Number 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). If you use a `while` loop instead, you will handle files with spaces just fine:

```
$ ls
'a file with spaces'
$ find . -type f | while read -r X; do date -r "$X"; done
Fri May 12 04:51:42 PM BST 2023
```

However, that will still fail on file names that contain newlines:

```
$ touch "$(printf 'a file with\na newline')"
$ ls
'a file with'$'\n''a newline'  'a file with spaces'
$ find . -type f | while read -r X; do date -r "$X"; done
date: './a file with': No such file or directory
date: 'a newline': No such file or directory
Fri May 12 04:51:42 PM BST 2023
```

To get around that, and assuming your `find` implementation supports it, you can use `-print0` to print null-terminated lines, and then use a loop that uses the NUL byte as a separator. Like this:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' X; do date -r "$X"; done
Fri May 12 04:53:06 PM BST 2023
Fri May 12 04:51:42 PM BST 2023
```

That said, by far the best approach is to use find's `-exec`, which unlike `-print0` is POSIX and portable, and also can handle arbitrary file names just fine:

```
$ find . -type f -exec date -r {} \;
Fri May 12 04:53:06 PM BST 2023
Fri May 12 04:51:42 PM BST 2023
```